# Webview in Activity Group crashing on dialogs

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that I'm creating in an Activity which is a child of an Activity Group.  The issue I'm having is that when I load an external weblink, the webview crashes when I click a link that would bring up a dialog:

```
03-28 12:06:24.189: E/AndroidRuntime(629): 
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
Unable to add window -- token 
android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44ef7060 is not valid;
is your activity running?
```

So basically the issue I'm having, I think, is very similar to this question:

[Webview crashes on select box or any Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755729/webview-crashes-on-select-box-or-any-dialog)

And the answer probably will work for me, the difference is that I'm declaring my webview from an xml file:

```
this.mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.proxSearchWebView);
```

I'm still very new to Android Dev, so I'm assuming that declaring my webview in this way is setting the context to "this" , is there a way to set the context to getParent() while still using XML?

So basically, is there a way to make this work while still defining the webview through XML or do I have to programmatically create the webview entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:` is basically due to context problem. Probably you are using the context of the current activity for create your dialog. You should use the parent activity context for create a dialog when you are using the Activity group.

You can get parent activity context by calling `getParent()`.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7631687/630668) that you can refer for the same issue

Comment: Even after getParent() for WebView inside TabHost, issue is there in >4.0 devices, yes its working fine for <2.3 devices. I will do research and post solution if i found any.